# How to use XamlReader for WPF templates in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, designer

I have been creating WPF for a few years now. My apps have a Generic.xaml file for styling standard and custom controls.

Starting with Visual Studio 2022, errors like these started appearing when you open Generic.xaml or one of my windows:

> Error XDG0062 'Cannot create unknown type '{clr-namespace:Configurator.Addin.Windows.Common.Controls;assembly=Configurator.Addin}Heading'.' Line number '4' and line position '14'.   Configurator.Addin  C:\Users\peter\Documents\visual-studio-2022-designer-templates\Configurator.Addin\Themes\Generic.xaml   161

I created a minimal repo [here](https://github.com/brinkdinges/visual-studio-2022-designer-templates). There is no file where line 4 is not a Using statement. The error goes away when I make my converter Public instead of Internal. I thought this was a bug in Visual Studio, so I reported it [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS2022-XAML-designer-needs-a-converter-t/10080265). This was their response:

> Main difference between VS 2019 and VS 2022 is that we stopped using FrameworkElementFactory. Per documentation, it is a deprecated way of creating templates and callers should use XamlReader. WPF designer in VS is a special WPF app (look for WpfSurface.exe in Task Manager). As such it is a subject of WPF limitations. Because WpfSurface.exe is not the same as your actual app, XamlReader will fail to load XAML containing internal types.

I understand all of those words, but I have no idea how I have to change my code. I have searched for hours, but I have not found any examples. What do I need to change?

The sample doesn't do anything because I build add-ins for another program, but it's the designer that's having issues anyway.

Comment: You say `The error goes away when I make my converter Public instead of Internal`, then the VS developer response was `[...] will fail to load XAML containing internal types`. And then you go on and say `but I have no idea how I have to change my code`. Really, you first said that you actually did find a way to fix your issue, then the VS-dev response says to the effect "_Yup, that's how you fix it. internal is not going to work anymore_". Then you say you don't know how to solve your problem despite having already found a way to fix it. Uh... what? (o.O)???

Comment: Fair point. I thought that was a quick workaround, and that I had to use XamlReader myself in some way. I have been avoiding public types as much as possible because they are added to the user's registry. If public types are now unavoidable, I'll have to find a way to prevent that.

Comment: I've narrowed down the types I need to make public: all converters that are mentioned in the Generic.xaml theme file, and _some_  custom controls. It's not very consistent.

Comment: For consistency look to what the XamlReader has to do.  If it needs to create an instance of a given class, you are going to need that class to be public